# Нагрев зарядного устройства

Tags: usb, железо

До какой адекватной температуры может нагреваться зарядное устройство при зарядке

- 5V - 1A, 2A и 3A
- 9V - 2A

Какую температуру при этом должен показывать такой измеритель?

**По сути вопрос в том, начиная с каких показаний стоит начинать волноваться?**
**А какие являются идеальными для каждого из видов зарядки?**

[image: измеритель]

[image: фото измерения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос реторический конечно, у большинства радиокомпонентов рабочая температура 25-40°C. Стоит заметить что некоторые радиодетали - такие как керамика могут спокойно держать температуру 90° и выше. Некоторые - такие как электролитические конденсаторы и высокочастотные транзисторы вообще не любят температуру выше комнатной 25° - первые высыхают вторые начинают себя вести непредсказуемо.

Для заметки домашний блок питания USB от телефона - может греться до 40° и это нормально.

Далее - температуры других немаловажных компонентов:

- Cвинецово-содержащими припой плавиться - 180–230°C
- Бессвинцовых припоев лежит в интервале 200–250°C
- Текстолит 230°С
- Фторопласт 600°С

Как пример - большинство хороших материнских плат сейчас делают из фторопласта и для них 120-150°С это нормальная температура (из серии чуток горяченькая).

Есть отдельные виды устройств - например блоки управления и питания для котельных.
Они базируются на фторопластовых платах, с стальными дорожками, полностью на керамике и вместо пайки используется сварка - для них температура в 200°С это совершенно рабочая температура.

Такой измеритель не показывает тебе температуру устройства - он показывает температуру шунтирующего резистора (Рш на картинке).

[image: C[Установка Шунтирующего резистора]

По сути как измеряется сила тока - в протекающий проводник ставиться некое сопротивление, и разница напряжений в точке А и B - как раз и будет твоя сила тока.

Comment: Интересно, но на вопрос по сути не отвечает... Во-первых, меня интересуют именно зарядные устройства, а не зарядка от компа. Во-вторых, в случае чего, скорее загорится пластиковый корпус, а не припой, или я не прав? В-третьих, я что-то не припомню ни одного зарядника, который бы работал без нагрева, так что нагрев для них вполне естественен. И логично предположить, что нагрев зависит от силы тока и напряжения. Т. е. я ожидал чего-то в духе "если разогревается до 100 градусов, то выкинь его пока не загорелся, а меньше 50 при 5V 3A в принципе не бывает".

Comment: Что касается измеряемой температуры, я понимаю, что они измеряют не совсем там, где надо, поэтому и добавил в вопрос уточнение про конкретный измеритель. Если нужна какая-то эмпирическая оценка температуры, то если вытащить измеритель и коснуться его металлического usb-разъёма (male), то: 51 градус - это можно спокойно дотрагиваться, но держать в руках скорее всего нельзя; 56 градусов - даже касаться уже сомнительно - на длительное время остаётся дискомфорт, но ожога нет.

Comment: Хм.. Или 40 градусов про блок от телефона и есть ответ? Можно подробнее эту часть? У меня зарядники, поддерживающие QC3 при 5V 3A греются один до 51, другой до 56, третий я ещё не замерял. При 9V 2A первый по-прежнему до 51, второй - вроде меньше. Те, которые выдают меньше - корпус менее горячий, измерителем не проверял.

Comment: Для домашнего зарядника для телефона 45-65 градусов на 3A - это вполне нормально. Пластик - (если не конченный китаец) не загорится а расплавиться! Если больше 70 - выбрасывай со спокойной душой!
Я больше занимаюсь индустриальным программированием и инженеркой. Если хочется так что поставил и забыл тогда глянь в сторону польской компании bergman их серия LPV-60-5 отлично для этого подходит. Как пример у меня USB розетки в стене и там-же замурованы бергмановские блоки питания на 5V 16A, они не греются, и имеют отличную защиту от перегруза.

Comment: Это по показаниям этого измерителя? Т. е. 45 - идеальный вариант, до 65 - допустимо? У меня один из тех, который до 51 греется начинает перезагружаться каждые несколько секунд когда доходит до 51, а второй такой же - остаётся на 51, но не перезагружается. Из-за этого поведения у меня и возникло подозрение, что 51 - это уже много. Померил на другом, а там оказалось 56))) Все китайские, тот, который с 56 - TOPK. C 51 - не могу оценить, но визуально сделан хорошо (не разборный, внутри не знаю). Ну и есть ещё один из дешёвых, его пока не измерил. А для быстрой зарядки (9V 2A) лимиты те же?

Comment: Эти штуки не убиваемые - https://bergmen.pl/en/power-supplies/lph-%e2%80%a2-lpv/  Там у них маркировка lph-60-5  (где lph - серия, 60 - уровень защиты, 5 - вольтаж) например lph-100-12 - будет lph с полной защитой (для влажной среды) на 12v

Comment: Китайцы вообще жутко мухлюют и на железе и на пластиках, перезагружаться он может из за очень многих причин - что могу посоветовать отнести в мастерскую тот который глючит, они спокойно разберут и уже по начинке спокойно скажут стоит его ремонтировать или отправить уже на покой. До 65 - вполне допустимо на быстро-зарядах и высоко-амперных.

Comment: Не, меня переносные интересуют. Менять розетки пока не в планах, плюс хочется один таскать с собой и один на работе оставить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105459/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-eugene-x).